# Infine template not showing correctly in IE using Hebrew characters

Tags: css, templates, fonts

menu items and other text elements using Hebrew in this [template](http://themeforest.net/item/infine-one-page-conference-event-template/full_screen_preview/4930324) for example will not display correctly in IE - the text appears as blank.

When editing the template default menu items and also in other parts of the page such as text in the `<small></small>` tags.
other browsers such as chrome don't have this issue.
have seen this strange behavior on WordPress templates as well.

Comment: A reference to a live page is not sufficient as a problem description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The font family:

```
font-family: "Open Sans","Arial",sans-serif;
```

specificaly "Open Sans" , does not support Hebrew on IE for some reason.need to use a different font.

This issue has also appeared on other templates and Wordpress themes such as  ["Wordpress child theme creator"](http://club.orbisius.com/products/wordpress-plugins/orbisius-child-theme-creator/) using this font.

Comment: Thanks, this really help me solve problem with a site.